# Sinon spy for named exports in ES6

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, sinon, enzyme

I use `enzyme` with `sinon` for unit testing React components. Normally, when it comes to testing instance methods I just spy on the method on instance of the component and assert respectively.

However, I have this global function that I use in many components of the app, which is a named export. `sinon` throws if I try to spy on that.

```
import { openModel } from '../global/handlers/';

<Block
   onRemove={(data) => openModal(...args)}
/>
```

So, currently I am calling prop method `onRemove` to assert that `openModal` gets called with the arguments but I can't really spy on the exported method i.e. `openModal`.

I understand that I need to provide a context to this function to be able to spy on the underlying function but I am not really sure what's the preferred way of doing something like this.

PS: I would be happy to provide more details if need be.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using webpack to build your test code, then you can use `inject-loader` to replace the imported module with a stub:

```
describe('Your component', () => {
    let openModalSpy;
    let Component;
    // Use whatever the path to your component is
    const injectImports = require('inject-loader!components/Component');

    beforeEach(() => {
        openModalSpy = sinon.spy();

        Component = injectImports({
            openModal: openModalSpy
        }).default;
    })

    it('calls open modal with data argument', () => {
        const wrapper = shallow(
            <Component />
        );

        // Do something that will result in openModal being called

        expect(openModalSpy).to.have.been.calledWith({
            // some data
        });
    }
}
```